# nghttpd connection closed automatically

Tags: telnet, httpserver, http2, nghttp2

I'm tryng to use nghttpd server to test HTTP/2.0. To start it i'm using:

```
sudo nghttpd --push=/test=/test1.png,/test2.pcapng,/test2.txt,/test3.png  --no-tls --workers=3  --early-response  -v  80.
```

In my CWD i've got the push files. In another terminal, i type:

```
telnet localhost 80
```

And everything seems ok, since i have this output in the first terminal

```
[id=1] [ 11.893] send SETTINGS frame <length=6, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
      (niv=1)
      [SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS(0x03):100]
[id=1] [ 21.898] send GOAWAY frame <length=8, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
      (last_stream_id=0, error_code=SETTINGS_TIMEOUT(0x04), opaque_data(0)=[])
```

The problems occur when i try an (any type of) HTTP GET with the second terminal:

```
telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /test HTTP/2.0
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

In my first terminal i get this output

```
[id=1] [314.531] closed
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little more elaboration: the HTTP/2 server sends control frames like `MAGIC`and `SETTINGS` (this includes information like Max Concurrent Streams and Initial Window Size) and the server does not honor the client until these are acknowledged by the client (in a `SETTINGS` frame as well).

*Telnet just establishes the TCP connection and then waits for the user to issue next packets.*

Without seeing these control frames in couple of seconds, the server closes the connection in couple of seconds.

This is in accordance to RFC 7540, section 6.5.3:

> If the sender of a SETTINGS frame does not receive an acknowledgement within a reasonable amount of time, it MAY issue a connection error (Section 5.4.1) of type SETTINGS_TIMEOUT.

This is the log of nghttpd (running in verbose mode) when I connected via Telnet:

```
[id=2] [ 34.645] send SETTINGS frame <length=6, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (niv=1)
          [SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS(0x03):100]
[id=2] [ 44.654] send GOAWAY frame <length=8, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (last_stream_id=0, error_code=SETTINGS_TIMEOUT(0x04), opaque_data(0)=[])
[id=2] [ 44.654] closed
```

In fact, in your question lies the answer, only that you printed the log of nghttpd server in parts. The server sent `GOAWAY` frame 10 seconds after sending the `SETTINGS` frame and closed the TCP connection.

Comment: I'm just reading the RFC 7540. Since nghttpd is a testing server, i can customize its requirement in order to estabilsh a connection with an empty SETTINGS frame (0-7 parameter it says, empty i mean with 0 paramenters) with the ack set. I'm working on this now. **Is the ack supposed to be in the TCP envelope? Is there a way to see an example frame?** I'm tryng to google it but i cannot find anything. I'm tryng to use wireshark to see an example of response in a HTTP/2 communication, but is impossible because the traffic is encrypted(TLS)

Comment: You can run nghttp2 over h2c.

`$ nghttpd -a 127.0.0.1 --no-tls -d ./htdoc 8080`

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 is a binary protocol, and you cannot use `telnet` like you could with HTTP/1.1.

You want to read carefully the [HTTP/2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) that describes that the HTTP/2 protocol is binary and requires to compress HTTP headers using [HPACK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541).
These two things combined make very difficult to use `telnet` and manual input to the socket; the usual way to interact with HTTP/2 server is to use HTTP/2 client tools.

Such client tools include `nghttp` itself and, among others, `curl`.

Comment: I solved using curl forcing http2 (after installing libcurl), but i would like to build and send a frame by myself maybe using nc or telnet if possible

Comment: It is possible, just that you have to write binary data and you have to figure out the HPACK encoding for the request line and headers by yourself - it's some work but doable.  Perhaps it's best that you use a tool to send a request, capture the network trace with `tcpdump` or similar, and then replay the bytes captured with `nc` or `telnet`.